# Error en conversion String a Double

Tags: android

Hola este es mi error y mi código.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.idjmatrillegmail.puntoventa, PID: 7566
>                     java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>                         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
>                         at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>                         at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
>                         at com.idjmatrillegmail.puntoventa.vista.creaCliente$1.onClick(creaCliente.java:61)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ESTE ES EL XML

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtLimiteCreditoCliente"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Limite de Credito"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtCelularCliente" />
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ESTA ES LA CLASE CLIENTE

```
public class Cliente {

    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private String direccion;
    private String sector;
    private String ciudad;
    private String cedula;
    private String telefono;
    private String celular;
    private double limiteCredito;
    private int diasCredito;
    private int usuarioCreador_id;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Cliente{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", nombre='").append(nombre).append('\'');
        sb.append(", apellidos='").append(apellidos).append('\'');
        sb.append(", direccion='").append(direccion).append('\'');
        sb.append(", sector='").append(sector).append('\'');
        sb.append(", ciudad='").append(ciudad).append('\'');
        sb.append(", cedula='").append(cedula).append('\'');
        sb.append(", telefono='").append(telefono).append('\'');
        sb.append(", celular='").append(celular).append('\'');
        sb.append(", limiteCredito=").append(limiteCredito);
        sb.append(", diasCredito=").append(diasCredito);
        sb.append(", usuarioCreador_id=").append(usuarioCreador_id);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getSector() {
        return sector;
    }

    public void setSector(String sector) {
        this.sector = sector;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public double getLimiteCredito() {
        return limiteCredito;
    }

    public void setLimiteCredito(double limiteCredito) {
        this.limiteCredito = limiteCredito;
    }

    public int getDiasCredito() {
        return diasCredito;
    }

    public void setDiasCredito(int diasCredito) {
        this.diasCredito = diasCredito;
    }

    public int getUsuarioCreador_id() {
        return usuarioCreador_id;
    }

    public void setUsuarioCreador_id(int usuarioCreador_id) {
        this.usuarioCreador_id = usuarioCreador_id;
    }

    public Cliente(String nombre, String apellidos, String direccion, String sector, String ciudad, String cedula, String telefono, String celular, double limiteCredito, int diasCredito, int usuarioCreador_id) {

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.sector = sector;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.cedula = cedula;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.celular = celular;
        this.limiteCredito = limiteCredito;
        this.diasCredito = diasCredito;
        this.usuarioCreador_id = usuarioCreador_id;
    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

AQUI TRATO DE PASAR EL VALOR

```
cliente.setLimiteCredito(Double.valueOf(limiteCredito.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el valor de tu clase es `double` (primitivo), tienes que usar un método que devuelva un tipo compatible. Cuando usas el método [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-double-) devuelve un `Double` (envoltorio, *wrapper* en inglés)  que no es lo mismo que un `double` (primitivo).

En este caso el método adecuado sería [**`parseDouble`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-), el cual está definido así:

> ```
> public static double parseDouble(String s)
>                           throws NumberFormatException
> ```
>
> Returns a new `double` initialized to the value represented by the
>   specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.
>
> Parameters: s - the string to be parsed.
>
> Returns: the `double` value represented by the string argument.
>
> Throws: 
>   `NullPointerException` - if the string is null
>
> `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable
>   double.

En efecto, este método recibe una cadena y devuelve un `double` (primitivo), que es lo que necesitas. Por tanto, así debería funcionar:

```
cliente.setLimiteCredito(Double.parseDouble(limiteCredito.getText().toString()));
```

Antes de hacer esto, convendría que verifiques o que controles las excepciones que el método puede generar: `NumberFormatException`, que puede ocurrir si el valor que tomas no es convertible a `double` y `NullPointerException` que ocurre si el valor escrito es nulo. En esos casos, si no controlas el error, tendrás un crash en tu código.

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
try{
    /*
       *Aquí usamos un ternario para asignar 0 cuando la cadena sea nula
       *así despejamos el NPE
    */
    String txt = limiteCredito.getText().toString() != null ? limiteCredito.getText().toString() : "0";

    double lCredito=Double.parseDouble(txt);
    cliente.setLimiteCredito(lCredito);

}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ 
   //manejar la excepción mostrando el error o enviando 0.00 a la clase...
}
```

De ese modo, si el usuario escribe `xyz` en el cuadro de texto o lo deja en blanco, la app no hará crash. Aunque conviene siempre aplicar restricciones en las entradas de datos. Por ejemplo, en un `TextView` que va a recoger un `double`, no permitir que se escriban datos indebidos o que quede en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es causado porque tratas de convertir una variable que contiene una cadena vacía ( "" ) a `Double`:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

como señalas el error ocurre en esta linea ya que el valor de `limiteCredito.getText().toString()` es `""`:

```
cliente.setLimiteCredito(Double.valueOf(limiteCredito.getText().toString()));
```

para esto puedes realizar un método para retornar un valor default en caso de que el valor en el `EditText` no pueda ser convertido a `Double`:

```
public static Double evaluaDouble(String number){
    Double resultado = 0.0; //Valor default si no es numerico.
    try{
        if(number != null){
            resultado = Double.valueOf(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        Log.w("Error", "NFException value: " + number);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

y llamas de esta forma el método:

```
cliente.setLimiteCredito(evaluaDouble(limiteCredito.getText().toString()));
```